# Multiple Laravel Eloquent Relationship

Tags: laravel-5, model, eloquent, relationship

I got stacked in laravel eloquent relationships. Here's the scenario:
I have `4 tables` in my database: 
    `Categories`,
    `Courses`,
    `Lessons`, and
    `Lesson_items`.
I have `3 more tables`:
    `category_course`,
    `course_lesson`, and
    `lesson_item_lesson`.
**Now**, I have these codes:

**Category.php** *- model*

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function courses(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Course');
    }
}
```

**routes.php** *- routes*

```
Route::get('/category/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'LearnController@getCategories'
]);
```

**MyController.php** *- controller*

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Category;
use App\Lesson;

class LearnController extends Controller
{
    public function getCategories($id){
        $categories = Category::find($id);
        $lessons = Lesson::find($categories);
        return view('categories', compact('categories', 'lessons'));
    }
}
```

**Now**, The result that I want is this:
[image]

**Really need your help guys.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [nested eager laoding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

**Category.php**

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function courses(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Course');
    }
}
```

**Course.php**

```
class Course extends Model
{
    public function lessons(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Lesson');
    }
}
```

**Lesson.php**

```
class Lesson extends Model
{
    public function lessonItems(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\LessonItem');
    }
}
```

**LessonItem.php**

```
class LessonItem extends Model
{
    public function lessons(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Lesson');
    }
}
```

Then in controller

```
class LearnController extends Controller
{
    public function getCategories($id){
        $categories = Category::with('courses.lessons.lessonItems')->find($id);
        return view('categories', compact('categories'));
    }
}
```

> Edit

You need some kind of this construction

```
@foreach ($category->courses as $course) {
    @foreach ($course->lessons as $lesson) {
        @foreach ($lesson->lessonItems as $item) {

        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: In `Lesson.php` and `LessonItem.php`, they have the same method? `courses()` ?

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo

Comment: Wait for a moment sir. Course is now working. How can I access the lessons, and lessonItems? to loop through

Comment: Wow! It worked men, you're so great.. Can I ask you later, if I still have trouble about it? Thank you so much .

Comment: is there a way to combine those relationships into one function in the category model? Like, I know this fails, but `$this->belongsTo(course)->belongsTo(lesson)->belongsTo(item)`. Then you can get the items using `Category::with('items')`